# Exclude traffic in Google Analytics coming from another page than my homepage

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

In my site:

`https://sp-marketing.com`

I have 2500 employees that enter from:

`https://sp-marketing.com/soysp/`

I want to exclude this page in my report, but I also want to exclude people who first access the homepage and then the same page. How can I do this?

Comment: If your employees only access the site from within the company, have you considered setting up an IP filter that would exclude all employee visits?

Comment: I showed how to create a segment in my answer below, but @nyuen's suggestion will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `Segment` that filters out the `Source` with the value of `https://sp-marketing.com/soysp/`
Here's an example:

[image]